# Padding or margin value in pixels as integer using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

jQuery has height() en width() functions that returns the height or width in pixels as integer...

How can I get a padding or margin value of an element **in pixels and as integer** using jQuery?

My first idea was to do the following:

```
var padding = parseInt(jQuery("myId").css("padding-top"));
```

But if padding is given in ems for example, how can I get the value in pixels?

---

Looking into the JSizes plugin suggested by Chris Pebble i realized that my own version was the right one :). jQuery returns always value in pixels, so just parsing it to integer was the solution.

Thanks to Chris Pebble and Ian Robinson

Comment: Can you please choose an answer from among the answers available below?

Comment: A note to people in this thread: always specify radix when you use `parseInt`.

Quoting MDN: "**radix** An int between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system. **Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior**. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10."
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 240):

You should be able to use CSS (http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name). You may have to be more specific such as "padding-left" or "margin-top".

Example:

**CSS**

```
a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {color:black;margin-top:10px;text-decoration: none;}
```

**JS**

```
$("a").css("margin-top");
```

The result is 10px.

If you want to get the integer value, you can do the following:

```
parseInt($("a").css("margin-top"))
```

Comment: I believe jQuery adds the "px" so we should be able to reliably expect its presence and remove it - see my edit above.

Comment: I haven't checked if the jQuery method actually returns the "px" suffix or not, however the `JSizes` plugin from the other answer (which I ended up using) returns an integer when the return value is passed into `ParseInt(...)`, just FYI.

Comment: FYI: jQuery does add the 'px', so Ian's solution works and will also return an integer when passed into parseInt() -- and it doesn't require a plugin: `parseInt($('a').css('margin-top').replace('px', ''))`

Comment: parseInt is faster than replace('px','') by 49% on chrome http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-parseint

Comment: in the latest chrome (21) this has switched, replace is now faster

Comment: If padding/margin is expressed as em or pt in the CSS, will `.css()` still return the value with "px" on the end?

Comment: @Bank That jsperf isn't running equivalent code - you're missing the conversion from string to int in the first case, and the parseInt() isn't safe. [They should be compared like this](http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-parseint/6)

Comment: @ingredient_15939 - Just tried it and yes; it calculates the actual pixel value and returns it with px. Same for border widths. Old question I know, but as no-one answered your question I thought I'd do it to help other latecomers...

Comment: Just to clarify what @Izkata said about `parseInt()` being unsafe. Without explicit radix parameter it is generally considered unsafe because it will then try to guess it. E.g. strings starting with 0x are considered as hex and some ancient JS implementations might consider strings starting with just 0 as octal. Then again, I doubt leading zeros are really possible in this case (except 0px which doesn't matter because `parseInt("0px", 8) === 0`), but it is also slightly faster making it, not only **a good practice**, but also **the most efficient way** of achieving this conversion.

Comment: @Rob: I'm looking at the test results for Chrome up to version 37 and parseInt is consistently significantly faster. On version 21 the differences are smaller but even on that version parseInt wins... It makes sense that parseInt would win as it is more specialized and therefore can be more optimized.

Comment: There is a [newer version](http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-parseint/6) of the test that adds the conversion step from string to int to the `replace` method and explicitly passes the radix to `parseInt`. In this scenario (which is more correct), `parseInt` wins by an even bigger margin: `replace` is 63 percent slower on my Chrome.

Comment: Seriously?  String replacement? How in the world does this have 128 votes?? Just use parseInt!

Comment: @RavenHursT Yeah maybe after almost 6 years I should update the answer and include parseInt.

Comment: Using `.replace('px', '')` does not return an integer. It returns a string stripped of  'px' characters. Use `parseInt($("a").css("margin-top"))` in order to get an integer value.

Comment: If you're writing CSS using relative units (em, ex rem etc) then you're likely to get decimals in your px value, and if you want to maintain that accuracy you can use parseFloat() instead. Wrapping that in Math.round can deal with long decimal values though I'm not sure if would actually be needed much

Answer (score 81):

Compare outer and inner height/widths to get the total margin and padding:

```
var that = $("#myId");
alert(that.outerHeight(true) - that.innerHeight());
```

Comment: i didnt realise outerHeight Existed. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Remember that outerWidth/Height includes border widths too though

Comment: innertWidth/innerHeight also include padding in their calculations, to get the width/height without padding, you need to use .width() and .height(). http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/ http://api.jquery.com/width/ http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: `that.outerHeight(true) - that.outerHeight()` would give the total vertical margins, because outerHeight() would include paddings and borders but exclude margins. See [api.jquery.com/outerWidth/](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

Comment: Agree with Andrew here (and have edited answer to say so), you need to use height instead of innerHeight to get total margin, border & padding

Answer (score 35):

The parseInt function has a "radix" parameter which defines the numeral system used on the conversion, so calling `parseInt(jQuery('#something').css('margin-left'), 10);` returns the left margin as an Integer.

This is what JSizes use.

Comment: Thanks for this, I hate having to include plugins for tiny pieces of functionality.

Comment: You don't even need to pass the "radix" since it defaults to 10.

Comment: Be aware that parseInt can return NaN (which then in turn make the calculations based on that variable fail) - add a isNaN check afterwards! Example case: `parseInt('auto', 10);` (`auto` is a valid `margin-left`).

Comment: @sethAlexanderBird your correct in stating that the radix will default to 10, however if code linting is important to you (and it probably should be) jsLint and jsHint will squawk at you if you leave it out.

Answer (score 31):

PLEASE don't go loading another library just to do something that's already natively available!

jQuery's `.css()` converts %'s and em's to their pixel equivalent to begin with, and `parseInt()` will remove the `'px'` from the end of the returned string and convert it to an integer:

http://jsfiddle.net/BXnXJ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $h1 = $('h1');
    console.log($h1);
    $h1.after($('<div>Padding-top: ' + parseInt($h1.css('padding-top')) + '</div>'));
    $h1.after($('<div>Margin-top: ' + parseInt($h1.css('margin-top')) + '</div>'));
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's how you can get the surrounding dimentions:

```
var elem = $('#myId');

var marginTopBottom  = elem.outerHeight(true) - elem.outerHeight();
var marginLeftRight  = elem.outerWidth(true)  - elem.outerWidth();

var borderTopBottom  = elem.outerHeight() - elem.innerHeight();
var borderLeftRight  = elem.outerWidth()  - elem.innerWidth();

var paddingTopBottom  = elem.innerHeight() - elem.height();
var paddingLeftRight  = elem.innerWidth()  - elem.width();
```

Pay attention that each variable, `paddingTopBottom` for example, contains the sum of the margins on the both sides of the element; i.e., `paddingTopBottom == paddingTop + paddingBottom`. I wonder if there is a way to get them separately. Of course, if they are equal you can divide by 2 :)

Comment: true = include margin.  +1000 internets

Comment: This is the best solution because it also works on `IE 7`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery#comment12529500_7779632

Answer (score 10):

You can just grab them as with [any CSS attribute](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS):

```
alert($("#mybox").css("padding-right"));
alert($("#mybox").css("margin-bottom"));
```

You can set them with a second attribute in the css method:

```
$("#mybox").css("padding-right", "20px");
```

EDIT: If you need just the pixel value, use `parseInt(val, 10)`:

```
parseInt($("#mybox").css("padding-right", "20px"), 10);
```

Comment: parseInt($("#mybox").css("padding-right", "20px"), 10);  - This works for me perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 9):

This simple function will do it:

```
$.fn.pixels = function(property) {
    return parseInt(this.css(property).slice(0,-2));
};
```

Usage:

```
var padding = $('#myId').pixels('paddingTop');
```

Comment: does not account for `auto`, `inherit` and `%` values

Comment: @Thomas: Not true. http://jsfiddle.net/nXyFN/ jQuery seems to return the result in pixels, always.

Comment: @Mark http://jsfiddle.net/BNQ6S/ IE7: `NaN`, it depends on the browser. As far as I know jQuery does not normalize `.css()` unlike `.width()` & `.height()`

Comment: @Thomas: Interesting. Ian's solution (top-rated) has the same problem too then. svinto's solution is probably best.

Answer (score 9):

Parse int

```
parseInt(canvas.css("margin-left"));
```

returns 0 for 0px

Answer (score 3):

ok just to answer the original question:

you can get the padding as a usable integer like this:

> var padding =
>   parseInt($("myId").css("padding-top").replace("ems",""));

If you have defined another measurement like px just replace "ems" with "px". 
parseInt interprets the stringpart as a wrong value so its important to replace it with ... nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You could also extend the jquery framework yourself with something like:

```
jQuery.fn.margin = function() {
var marginTop = this.outerHeight(true) - this.outerHeight();
var marginLeft = this.outerWidth(true) - this.outerWidth();

return {
    top: marginTop,
    left: marginLeft
}};
```

Thereby adding a function on your jquery objects called margin(), which returns a collection like the offset function.

fx.

```
$("#myObject").margin().top
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give you the top and left margins, but rather the totalVertical and totalHorizontal margins

Comment: However it could be edited using the parseInt function in one of the other solutions to allow a more seamless appearing margin function

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string.replace("px", ""));

Use parseInt or parseFloat!

Answer (score 0):

I probably use [github.com/bramstein/jsizes](https://github.com/bramstein/jsizes) jquery plugin for paddings and margins in very comfortable way, Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly adopted from [Quickredfox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1901665/1250044).

```
jQuersy.fn.cssNum = function(){
    return parseInt(jQuery.fn.css.apply(this, arguments), 10);
};
```

**update**

Changed to `parseInt(val, 10)` since it is faster than `parseFloat`.

http://jsperf.com/number-vs-plus-vs-toint-vs-tofloat/20

Answer (score 0):

Not to necro but I made this which can determine pixels based on a variety of values:

```
$.fn.extend({
  pixels: function (property, base) {
    var value = $(this).css(property);
    var original = value;
    var outer = property.indexOf('left') != -1 || property.indexOf('right') != -1 
      ? $(this).parent().outerWidth()
      : $(this).parent().outerHeight();

    // EM Conversion Factor
    base = base || 16;

    if (value == 'auto' || value == 'inherit') 
        return outer || 0;

    value = value.replace('rem', '');
    value = value.replace('em', '');

    if (value !== original) {
       value = parseFloat(value);
       return value ? base * value : 0;
    }

    value = value.replace('pt', '');

    if (value !== original) {
       value = parseFloat(value);
       return value ? value * 1.333333 : 0; // 1pt = 1.333px
    }

    value = value.replace('%', '');

    if (value !== original) {
      value = parseFloat(value);
      return value ? (outer * value / 100) : 0;
    }

    value = value.replace('px', '');
    return parseFloat(value) || 0;
  }
});
```

This way, we take into account for sizing, and auto / inherit.

Comment: Note that `parseInt()` is wrong, the width or height can be floating points.