# How to get just numeric part of CSS property with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parsing

I need to do a numeric calculation based on CSS properties. However, when I use this to get info:

```
$(this).css('marginBottom')
```

it returns the value '10px'. Is there a trick to just getting the number part of the value no matter whether it is `px` or `%` or `em` or whatever?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This will clean up all non-digits, non-dots, and not-minus-sign from the string:

```
$(this).css('marginBottom').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
```

UPDATED for negative values

Comment: This is great providing you aren't dealing with negative numbers. I'm no regex guru so can't provide a better sample :)

Comment: Consider using **[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)** which handles **all** characters allowed in floating point numbers and also returns a **number** instead of a string - see [maximelebreton's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896719/177710).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because it does not answer the question correctly. The parseFloat/parseInt solutions are better. The question asks in regards to **numeric calculations**. This answer returns a string. That means that "20" + 20 = "2020" which is not good for anyone involved.

Comment: @zakovyrya could you explain the used RegExp `/[^-\d\.]/g`

Comment: @Alexander Square brackets with caret means NOT: [^<whatever you put here>]. In this regex it matches any symbol which is NOT minus sign, digit or dot. Essentially deletes everything that cannot be part of the number

Answer (score 299):

```
parseInt($(this).css('marginBottom'), 10);
```

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will automatically ignore the units.

For example:

```
var marginBottom = "10px";
marginBottom = parseInt(marginBottom, 10);
alert(marginBottom); // alerts: 10
```

Comment: This seems to work very well in all cases I've stumbled upon, and I find it much more readable than any regexp solutions.

Comment: you might want to add the radix (10) to parseInt if you are using this solution.

Comment: You might want to use **[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)** instead of `parseInt` to account for the case where you receive a non-integer value - as in [maximelebreton's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896719/177710).

Comment: This is also better than the regex as it doesn't return the value as a string.

Comment: Actually, parseInt doesn't need ", 10" radix parameter, since 10 is default. Less params = better readability, shorter code, less bugs.

Comment: 10 is only the default for parseInt if the number can't can be interpreted as an octal (e.g. '0700' would parse as 448 rather than 700, which is probably what's desired).

Comment: If the value is undefined or null, then `parseInt(value)` will return `NaN`, so you may wish to protect your code using `isNaN(value)` to be sure.

Comment: There's another advantage to this solution compared to the regex one -- the result type in this case is Number and any arithmetic works as expected.  The result type in the regex solution is String.

Answer (score 128):

With the replace method, your css value is a string, and not a number.

This method is more clean, simple, and returns a number :

```
parseFloat($(this).css('marginBottom'));
```

Comment: This is the best solution, since OP is asking for possible non-integer units (`%`, `em`)

Answer (score 15):

```
parseFloat($(this).css('marginBottom'))
```

Even if marginBottom defined in em, the value inside of parseFloat above will be in px, as it's a calculated CSS property.

Comment: [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) has only one argument - the radix (10) you provided here will be ignored. So the more correct answer would be [maximelebreton's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896719/177710).

Comment: Does it need to be      parseFloat($(this).css('marginBottom'), 10)

Answer (score 9):

```
$(this).css('marginBottom').replace('px','')
```

Comment: That would handle only the 'px' case. So I guess a separate replace should be done for each of the remaining 'suffixes'.

Comment: Be careful thought - the other suffixes are not in pixels, so if you expect `px` but are given `em` you need to convert.

Comment: that's what I was thinking -- are there any library routines for this? Like I think it's a pretty reasonable condition to expect px, but for the purposes of robustness, what are our options...? (Just musing, here - I'm not going to bother too much with it since I control the values)

Answer (score 6):

Let us assume you have a margin-bottom property set to 20px / 20% / 20em. To get the value as a number there are two options:

**Option 1:**

```
parseInt($('#some_DOM_element_ID').css('margin-bottom'), 10);
```

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer. Don't change the 10 found in the above function (known as a "radix") unless you know what you are doing.

*Example Output* will be: 20 (if margin-bottom set in px) for % and em it will output the relative number based on current Parent Element / Font size.

**Option 2** *(I personally prefer this option)*

```
parseFloat($('#some_DOM_element_ID').css('margin-bottom'));
```

*Example Output* will be: 20 (if margin-bottom set in px) for % and em it will output the relative number based on current Parent Element / Font size.

The parseFloat() function parses a string and returns a floating point number.

The parseFloat() function determines if the first character in the specified string is a number. If it is, it parses the string until it reaches the end of the number, and returns the number as a number, not as a string.

The advantage of Option 2 is that if you get decimal numbers returned (e.g. 20.32322px) you will get the number returned with the values behind the decimal point. Useful if you need specific numbers returned, for example if your margin-bottom is set in **em** or **%**

Answer (score 5):

I use a simple jQuery plugin to return the numeric value of any single CSS property.

It applies `parseFloat` to the value returned by jQuery's default `css` method.

**Plugin Definition:**

```
$.fn.cssNum = function(){
  return parseFloat($.fn.css.apply(this,arguments));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var element = $('.selector-class');
var numericWidth = element.cssNum('width') * 10 + 'px';
element.css('width', numericWidth);
```

Answer (score 4):

`parseint` will truncate any decimal values (e.g. `1.5em` gives `1`).

Try a `replace` function with regex 
e.g.

```
$this.css('marginBottom').replace(/([\d.]+)(px|pt|em|%)/,'$1');
```

Answer (score 4):

Id go for:

```
Math.abs(parseFloat($(this).css("property")));
```

Comment: Not a generic solution. In most of cases, I think, I will want to know a `margin` is negative or positive!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get the element width without units is :

```
target.width()
```

Source : https://api.jquery.com/width/#width2

Comment: Great for width and height. $(selector).width() and $(selector).height() are indeed numbers. Not useful for other css props: margin, padding.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this very simple **jQuery** plugin:

**Plugin Definition:**

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.cssValue = function(p) {
      var result;
      return isNaN(result = parseFloat(this.css(p))) ? 0 : result;
   };
})(jQuery);
```

It is resistant to `NaN` values that may occur in old IE version (will return `0` instead)

**Usage:**

```
$(this).cssValue('marginBottom');
```

Enjoy! :)

Comment: This is a good idea, but remember to watch out for side effects like calling a function of unknown cost more than necessary.  `var result; return isNaN(result = parseFloat(this.css(p))) ? 0 : result;`

Answer (score 2):

For improving accepted answer use this:

```
Number($(this).css('marginBottom').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for "px" you can also use:

```
$(this).css('marginBottom').slice(0, -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should remove units while preserving decimals.

```
var regExp = new RegExp("[a-z][A-Z]","g");
parseFloat($(this).css("property").replace(regExp, ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
$(this).cssUnit('marginBottom');
```

which return an array.
first index returns margin bottom's value(example **20** for 20px)
and second index returns margin bottom's unit(example **px** for 20px)

Comment: cssUnit is actually a part of jQueryUI, not jQuery.