# jQuery: Getting px position of an element in Integer format

Tags: jquery, position

This code works in FF, but not in IE:

```
parseInt($('.scroller').css('left');
```

In FF it returns 0px;

In IE it returns `NaN`.

What's a good way to get a pixel position of an element?

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="scroller">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$('.scroller').offset().left;
```

`offset()` returns an object containing the properties `left` and `top`, which are the position values relative to the document in pixels.

If you want the position relative to the parent element, use [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) instead.

Comment: It does seem that there are cases where neither offset() nor position() give the desired value.  I have a relatively positioned element and in my case, offset() and position() both return the same value and it is different from $('element').css('left').   It is the css left value that I need.  For now I am using parseInt($('.element').css('left').replace('px', '')).  I suspect the reason why IE chocked on kylex's attempt is that it has 'px' on the end.  Stripping that off seems to play well with IE.  Does anyone know of a better way to do this in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It would be however always relative to document, therefore position() (relative to parent, i.e. holder) would sometimes be rather accurate and sometimes none of them.