# jQuery value for 'right' on fixed element without 'px'

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

There are a few similar titles to this (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043102/how-to-get-right-offset-of-an-element-jquery), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690463/get-a-number-for-a-style-value-without-the-px-suffix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652546/jquery-getting-px-position-of-an-element-in-integer-format)), but I refuse to believe it's as complicated as they seem to indicate. The following gives the value '20px'. How can I get it to just return '20'?

```
var base=$('#id').css('right');
```

Comment: `parseInt($('#id').css('right'))` ?

Comment: If .css() returns `auto` then you need a combination of left and width.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`parseInt()` returns the parsed integer.

```
var cssValue = $('#id').css('right'); //returns 20px
var parsedCssValue = parseInt(cssValue); //returns 20
```