# jquery div animation on mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck with second of my simple animation in jquery and css. what i am try to achieve when user click on "search_TextBox" selector, the div with searchFormWrapper_01 selector goes to position from (left) -280px to 0 with animation on horizontal scale, which is working perfectly however searchFormWrapper_01 does go back to -280 when user click second time...

seems my else if condition not responding ... i am sure it will something small silly mistake but i need help... many thanks

### jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search_TextBox").click(function () {


            if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") != 0) {
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
            }

            else if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") == 0){
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: -280 }, 'fast');
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

### html

```
 <div class="container">   
    <div class="searchFormWrapper_01">
        <div class="search_form"> my content </div>
        <span id="search_TextBox">my image</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### css

```
container {
    background-color:red;
    width:66em;
    height:375px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.searchFormWrapper_01 {
    width:330px;
    height:375px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
    left:-280px;
}

.search_form {
    float:left;
    width:270px;
    height:375px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-left:10px;
}

 #search_TextBox{ 
     float:left;
     width:50px;
     height:375px; 
     background:url("../Content/themes/base/images/searchText.png") no-repeat;
 }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tfTK3/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_TextBox").click(function () {
        if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") != '0px') {
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: '0px' }, 'fast');
        } else {
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: '-280px' }, 'fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Your code didn't work because 0 isn't the same as 0px.

Answer (score 2):

`$(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left")` is not equal to 0 (zero) after a first click but is actually equal to `0px`. Just change your equality in the statements and it should be ok.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfTK3/8/)

Comment: i tried just using else but it seems my else if not responding for some reason

Comment: Check my edit, you alse have to change the first if statment ;)

Comment: i tried else if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") == 0+"px"){ but its still not responding!!!

Comment: That's because the if statement is always true. The .css('left') is equal to '0px', not to 0 (zero). So the .css('left') will, in both case, be different from 0 ! Be sure to check the fiddle in my original post to see the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search_TextBox").click(function () {
        if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") != '0px') {
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
        } else if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") == '0px'){
            console.log('a', $(".searchFormWrapper_01"))
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: -280 }, 'fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tfTK3/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statements to compare the value:

```
if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") != '0px')
```

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfTK3/5/)

`.css('left')` will always return a value, so it will never `== 0`

Answer (score 1):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/KBYP7/1/

```
$("#search_TextBox").click(function () {
 if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") === '-280px'){
        $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 'fast');
    } else if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left") === '0px') {
        $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({
            left: '-280px'
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when I do something like this I am adding a css-class to be very sure of the state of my div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search_TextBox").click(function () {


            if ($(".searchFormWrapper_01").hasClass('moved-left') ) {
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").removeClass('moved-left');
            }

            else {
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: -280 }, 'fast');
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").addClass('moved-left');
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

A good thing having that class added is, that you can also use css-animations.

Answer (score 1):

hope this help http://jsfiddle.net/xSCFZ/1/
the css attribute isn't necessary an int; you have "0px"..
[How to get just numeric part of CSS property with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery)

the parseInt http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

$("#search_TextBox").click(function () {

```
   var left = parseInt($(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left"),10);
        if ( left != 0) {
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
        }

        else {
            $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: -280 }, 'fast');
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this way and it works ... many thank to everyone for response

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#search_TextBox").click(function () {

            $current_WrapperPostion = $(".searchFormWrapper_01").css("left");

            if ($current_WrapperPostion == -280+"px") {
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: 0 }, 'fast');
            }

            else if ($current_WrapperPostion == 0+"px"){
                $(".searchFormWrapper_01").animate({ left: -280 }, 'fast');
            }
        });
    });
```