# How to subtract text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I subtract text with jQuery?

I tried to use minus to delete the text, but it doesn't work.

```
var coluna = $('.coluna').css('width');
```

In this line, the value outputted is `"300px"`, and I want to remove `"px"` to get just the number `300`.

Comment: use .width() which will return the width as a number, otherwise you would need to use parseInt on the returned value from the css call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of using

```
var coluna = $('.coluna').css('width');
```

(Which returns a string)

use this:

```
var coluna = $('.coluna').width();
```

(Which returns an integer)

---

If you ever find yourself needing to actually split strings, take a look at [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)