# jQuery calculating 2 different HTML element attributes (height + margin-bottom)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the height and the margin-bottom of a element, and count them up. But so far, i can only do this:

```
var sum = $('div').height() + 25);
```

That `25` i had to look up myself in the stylesheet at

```
div {
   height: 75px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

How can i make this automaticly?

Because when i try:

```
var sum = $('div').height() + $('div').css('margin-bottom');
```

It isnt returning any value.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what it is returning?  It should return "a value" just not what you think it will.  have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/ which includes the margins, padding and borders (all which count towards the total height, along with the base height). Alternatively, you can use `parseInt($('div').css('margin-bottom'))` because the value is a css string that looks something like this: `100px`. `parseInt()` would extract the `100` from that css, which is what you want.

In addition, you're kinda doing it wrong in general. Are you looking for the sum of all the heights of all the `div` elements? Or does your page have only one div?

Comment: FYI: If you want to sum the `height()`s (or `outerHeight()`s) of all the `div`s, you should probably look at jquery's `each` (http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many 'div' elements in a document(usually).
You need a better selector for the one you want.
[Fiddle for value in console.log](http://jsfiddle.net/rM2L2/)

```
<div id="TestId" class="test"></div>
```

---

```
.test
{
height:40px;
margin:5px;
}
```

---

```
var tester = $("#TestId");
var eleHeight = tester.outerHeight();
var marginBottomHeight = tester.css('margin-bottom').replace("px", "")
console.log(eleHeight + parseInt(marginBottomHeight));
```

Comment: It was an example... :P

Answer (score 0):

`$('div').css('margin-bottom')` will have the px attached. Try and use something like `parseInt()`

```
var sum = $('div').height() + parseInt($('div').css('margin-bottom'), 10);
```

W