# jQuery - Side Sliding Menu

Tags: jquery, css

What is the best method to have slide out menu animate properly upon opening and closing? The slide out menu should animate in and out smoothly upon clicking the "open/close" button, pushing all contents in the body aside.

The jQuery:

```
var body = $('body');
var button = $('#button');
var menu = $('#menu');
var menuWidth = $('#menu').width();

menu.css({ right: -menuWidth });
button.html('OPEN');

button.on('click', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    body.animate({ right: 'menuWidth' });

    if (body.css({ right: 0 })) {
        body.animate({
            right: +menuWidth
        }, 600);
        button.html('CLOSE');
    } else {
        body.animate({
            right: 0
        }, 600);
        button.html('OPEN');
    }

});
```

The slide currently jumps upon clicking the "close" button and then reanimates back open, without clicking the "open" button.

A link to the current example, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/xv3n257x/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see a reason for the need of `body.animate({ right: 'menuWidth' });` in its first occurence, so I'd suggest to remove it. (Anyway, this line triggers the one and only animation you currently have)

The actual problem is your condition.
I did not figure out why your condition does not work, since it seems to be correct, but changing it to `if (body.css('right')=='0px')`does the trick.

Finally, you have to set the initial value for the body's `right` property:

```
body{
  right: 0;
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, it is being set to `right: auto` by the browser. Then, your first click would set it to 0 but obviously, will not have any visible effect.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu0vkcbr/)

Answer (score 0):

it appears your 'body.css' line is actually setting the right value to 0 every time.  so, replace this line:

```
if (body.css({ right: 0 })) {
```

with this line:

```
if (body.css('right').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') == 0) {
```

I have to give credit to another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery) for stripping off the 'px' characters of the css value retrieved to compare to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser requirements support it, one option is to use CSS transitions to animate the menu based on just changing its class:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upc3pcsw/)

```
#menu {
    width: 0;
    transition: width .6s;
}
#menu.open {
    width:300px;
}
```