# How to make an image click() after Keydown Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that moves over divs. I have methods that are called after each div is clicked. How do i make my image simulate a mouseclick after it has been moved. 
My code :

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
     $("#img").animate({marginLeft: "+=107px"}, {queue:false}, "slow");
     return false;
}
```

(39) Being the right move . 
So after I click the right keyboard button , i want my image to move to the right (DONE) and then a mouseclick to click at the center of this image to click on the divs behind it.

I cant use the `trigger()` and `click()` functions because I don't know which corresponding divisor the image is over and hence cant `$(#...)`

The image moves perfectly over the divisors though.

```
<div id="Blocks">
          <div id="41" class="square" ></div>
          <div id ="42" class="square" ></div>
          <div id ="43" class="square" ></div>
          <div id ="44" class="square" ></div>
      </div>
      <div id ="Blocks2">
          <div id ="31" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="32" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="33" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="34" class="square"></div>
      </div>
      <div id ="Blocks3">
          <div id ="21" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="22" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="23" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="24" class="square"></div>
      </div>
      <div id ="Blocks4">
          <div id ="11"  class="square" ></div>
          <div id ="12" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="13" class="square"></div>
          <div id ="14" class="square"></div>
      </div>
```

Image moves over one of these divs , need to fire an event to know over which div id it is

Comment: You should provide minimalistic sample which replicates your issue

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Please post a snippet that shows your markup (at least the divs and image), and more JS code, at least show your entire event handler for `keydown` or whatever (I assume `keydown`, but you didn't specify.)

Answer (score 0):

1- Click is always registered on the upper-most div ( higher z-index ) that's under the cursor.
* You can't click "behind"
2- " because i dont know which corresponding divisor the image is over and hence cant $(#...) "
is false: you CAN find the div under your current position, because:
* you know your cursor coordinates
* you can know your divs offset ( = coordinates )

[Proof: there's a plugin for that](http://yckart.github.io/jquery.overlaps.js/jquery.overlaps.js)

Comment: been a while since it worked but ye. Thats exactly what i did. used the coordinates. cheers bud

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the jQuery `animate()` function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you can define a function to be called on `complete` (when the animation is finished).

Here is a working example (really rough method; definitely not the method I would use, and can be improved in numerous ways; would be better to use knowledge of matrix of divs instead of relying on CSS position (ie, extend the `data` object usage further), and replace hardcoded dimensions with width/height programmatically, etc.).

I also recommend using `queue: true` instead of `false` because it will be easier to manage (your example has a problem right now if user hits the key quickly multiple times in a row)

Scroll down to end of code and click "Run Snippet" and click "Full page" for best results.

```js
$(document.body).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
    var $img = $("#img");
    var dir = e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 38 ? -1 : 1
    var axis = e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40 ? "top" : "left";
    var data = $img.data("goal"); // used to restrict movement at bounds

    if (!data) {
      data = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      };
      $img.data("goal", data);
    }

    var pos = (axis === "left" ? data.left : data.top);
    if ((dir > 0 && pos < 180) || (dir < 0 && pos > 0)) {
      var moveAmt = 60 * dir;
      if (axis === "left") {
        data = {
          left: data.left + moveAmt,
          top: data.top
        };
      } else {
        data = {
          top: data.top + moveAmt,
          left: data.left
        };
      }
      $img.data("goal", data);
      var moveCmd = {};
      moveCmd[axis] = "+=" + moveAmt + "px";
      $img.animate(moveCmd, {
        queue: true, // easier to manage than 'false'
        speed: "slow",
        easing: "swing",
        complete: function() {
          // this function is called when animation completes
          $(this).addClass("moved");
          // get number; from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery
          var imgLeft = +($(this).css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')); // coerce to number
          var imgTop = +($(this).css('top').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '')); // coerce to number
          $(".square").each(function() {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            if (offset.left === imgLeft && offset.top === imgTop) {
              var fromKeyboard = true;
              $(this).trigger("click", [fromKeyboard]);
              return false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
});

$(".square").on("click", function(e, fromKeyboard) {
  var str = "Clicked " + this.id;
  if (fromKeyboard) {
    str += " (FROM KEYBOARD)";
  }
  $("#feedback").html(str);
});
```

```css
BODY {
  margin: 0;
}
DIV {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#img {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid Red;
  background-color: Blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#img.moved {
  background-color: Orange;
}
.square {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 5px solid #666;
}
.row {
  font-size: 0;
}
#feedback {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="Blocks" class="row">
  <div id="41" class="square"></div>
  <div id="42" class="square"></div>
  <div id="43" class="square"></div>
  <div id="44" class="square"></div>
</div>
<div id="Blocks2" class="row">
  <div id="31" class="square"></div>
  <div id="32" class="square"></div>
  <div id="33" class="square"></div>
  <div id="34" class="square"></div>
</div>
<div id="Blocks3" class="row">
  <div id="21" class="square"></div>
  <div id="22" class="square"></div>
  <div id="23" class="square"></div>
  <div id="24" class="square"></div>
</div>
<div id="Blocks4" class="row">
  <div id="11" class="square"></div>
  <div id="12" class="square"></div>
  <div id="13" class="square"></div>
  <div id="14" class="square"></div>
</div>
<div id="feedback">Click into the document area and then hit the ARROW keys</div>
```

In the `complete` function you can put the code for simulating the mouse click. If you know the dimensions of `#img` and the divs and their positions, you can probably use some collision detection logic to figure out which one to click, then it is a simple matter of firing the `click` event on the target element.

You need to post your markup that shows these DIVS and #img before we can help you further tho..

Comment: Note that the CSS is just used to simulate the image that moves with keyboard input.