# jquery .css("width") with two values

Tags: jquery

I want to have a jquery function that runs if the width of my div (.slider) is between 650px and 521px. I have this so far for code which isn't working and I am unsure of how to write the greater than less than part:

```
} else if ($(".slider").css("width") < "651px" || > "520px") {
```

I am getting this error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

*******UPDATE***** I am now using:

```
 var w = parseFloat($('.slider').css('width')) 

 if (w > 651) {
              //do something here
 } else if (w < 651 || w > 520) {
              //do something here
 } else if (w <= 520) {
             //do something here
 } else {
            //do something here
 }
```

but for some reason it is stuck at the 'else if (w < 651 || w > 521)' conditional so when my div is less than 520 in width it is still firing what's inside that conditional.

Comment: expression wrong ? + cant compare  strings as number values (num+'px')!!

Comment: I know the expression is wrong. Is there a solution to the "cant compare strings as number values (num+'px')" problem?

Comment: well, it's getting stuck because it will always be either smaller than 651 or bigger than 520, so that elseif will always return true. you need && not ||

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjyoqdpv/

jQuery

```
$(function()
{
    var flexWidth = $('.flex').css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
  if(flexWidth > 550 || flexWidth < 660)
  {
    alert("If statement is true");
  }
});
```

Using the `jQuery.css` this will return the value, however because it will return `550px` this can't be used to check if greater or lesser than because it is a string. So you need to find convert it to a number (remove the px). Once you have the numeric value you can then use it correctly for your if statement.

Coverting css property to number URL: [How to get just numeric part of CSS property with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery)

Comment: This. is good except that flexWidth here is still a string. Although js would convert it during the comparison, `parseInt` or `parseFloat` might work better.
`var flexWidth = parseFloat($('.flex').css('width'))`

Comment: You don't need the `if (w > "651")`

Comment: @Canvas sorry my copy & paste went bad. I am using:                                                     if (w > 651) {
              //do something here
 } else if (w < 651 || w > 520) {
              //do something here
 } else if (w <= 520) {
             //do something here
 } else {
            //do something here
 } 
but for some reason it is stuck at the 'else if (w < 651 || w > 521)' conditional so when my div is less than 520 in width it is still firing what's inside that conditional.

Comment: Change you `||` or statement to a `&&` and statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the variable to each side.

```
} else if ($(".slider").css("width") < "651px" || $(".slider").css("width") > "520px") {
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct  mode is:
(another note: using multiple time $(".slider") slow up the performance)

```
 var w = $(".slider").width();
/**tons of code here**/
else if (w < 651 || w > 520) {
/** **/
```

Comment: This compares two strings though. Consider the case where "540px" < "525600px"  returns false.

Comment: Not really! The jQuery width() function return a float not a string variable

Comment: My comment refers to a previous version of the answer that used `.css('width')`