# Selecting a parent when a click event is fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select parent element when a click event is fired. I'm trying the following. I have 5 sidebar box with the same class and different content like below.

At first, the sidebar box shows some content and when we click the read more button it shows the rest content of the parent element. After that, the read more button is hiding in the parent box and the close button is showing, But it's showing all other boxes, not the parent box.

So, How can I select my only the parent close button? Please check my javascript code below.

```
<div class="artist_bio sidebar-box">

    <!-- Default Show this text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, exercitationem.</p>

    <!-- After Clcik on .read-more-button it's showes -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button moretag read-more-button">Read More</a></p>
    <p class="read-less"><a href="#" class="button read-less-button">Close</a></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript is Here-

```
$(function() {

            var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;
            var $orgHeight = $('.sidebar-box').height();

            $(".sidebar-box .read-more-button").click(function() {

                totalHeight = 0

                $el = $(this); $p  = $el.parent(); $up = $p.parent();
                $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

                $ps.each(function() {
                    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                    // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
                });

                $up
                    .css({
                        "height": $up.height(),
                        "max-height": 9999,
                        "opacity": 1,
                    })

                   .animate({
                        "height": totalHeight
                    },500,function(){

                    //Callback - after the animation is over
                    jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry(); });

                // fade out read-more
                $p.fadeOut();
                $('.read-less-button').fadeIn(50);

                // prevent jump-down
                return false;

            });

  /*Another Code*/
            $(".sidebar-box .read-less-button").click(function() {

                $el = $(this);
                $p  = $el.parent();
                $up = $p.parent();
                totalHeight = $up.height();

                $up
                    .css({

                        "height": totalHeight,
                        "max-height": 9999
                    })

                   .animate({
                        "height": $orgHeight
                    },500,function(){

                    //Callback - after the animation is over
                    jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry(); });

                // fade out read-less
                $p.fadeOut();
                $('.read-more').fadeIn();


                // prevent jump-down
                return false;

            });

        });
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not a  javascript expert. I am learning. Not actually. @AluanHaddad

Comment: If I read it correctly, you can use `.closest("parent_selector")` then `.find(close_button)`. In your case it would be `.closest(".sidebar-box")`

Comment: @Huangism I think it will work. Let me check please.

Comment: That is better. Note that `$` is a to reference `jQuery` you should pick one or the other (`$` or `jQuery`) and use it consistently. Also, add `"use strict";` as the very first line of your program.

Comment: I think it is failing in the spot you're mentioning because it will return something like "10px" for example.  Then when you try to do += to it, it fails.  You can't just add them in JavaScript, because it doesn't know how to add a "10px" string to "10px", for example, if the height and margin were both 10px.  You would end up with "10px10px" I believe.  Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100503/how-to-get-just-numeric-part-of-css-property-with-jquery

Comment: Is this something you're looking into achieving? https://jsfiddle.net/fucyqtmv/

Comment: @ZakirHossain I didn't do anything... but you are welcome :)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry It's not you. I

Comment: Thanks, @Huangism it works. Here the code- jQueryp.closest('.sidebar-box').find('.read-less').fadeIn();

Comment: @ZakirHossain great, I added an answer for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a parent that could be levels up use `.closest()`

`.closest("parent_selector")` then `.find(close_button)`. In your case it would be

```
$el.closest(".sidebar-box").find('.read-less')
```

Here is the documentation on closest https://api.jquery.com/closest/

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly, but if you refactor it you should be able to get it to work well.

I commented out your **masonry** methods, because those weren't included.

I think this should get you started.  It appears it is because you were adding strings together, not numbers.

```js
$(function() {

            var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;
            var $orgHeight = $('.sidebar-box').height();

            $(".sidebar-box .read-more-button").click(function() {

                totalHeight = 0

                $el = $(this); $p  = $el.parent(); $up = $p.parent();
                $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

                $ps.each(function() {
                    totalHeight += parseInt($(this).outerHeight());
                    totalHeight += parseInt($(this).css("margin-bottom").replace('px',''));
                });

                $up
                    .css({
                        "height": $up.height(),
                        "max-height": 9999,
                        "opacity": 1,
                    })

                   .animate({
                        "height": totalHeight
                    },500,function(){

                    //Callback - after the animation is over
                    //jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry(); 
                    });

                // fade out read-more
                $p.fadeOut();
                $('.read-less-button').fadeIn(50);

                // prevent jump-down
                return false;

            });

  /*Another Code*/
            $(".sidebar-box .read-less-button").click(function() {

                $el = $(this);
                $p  = $el.parent();
                $up = $p.parent();
                totalHeight = $up.height();

                $up
                    .css({

                        "height": totalHeight,
                        "max-height": 9999
                    })

                   .animate({
                        "height": $orgHeight
                    },500,function(){

                    //Callback - after the animation is over
                    //jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry(); 
                    });

                // fade out read-less
                $p.fadeOut();
                $('.read-more').fadeIn();


                // prevent jump-down
                return false;

            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="artist_bio sidebar-box">

    <!-- Default Show this text -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, exercitationem.</p>

    <!-- After Clcik on .read-more-button it's showes -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button moretag read-more-button">Read More</a></p>
    <p class="read-less"><a href="#" class="button read-less-button">Close</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you remove the `alert(totalHeight);`

Comment: I have removed it.  May I ask why you would like it to be removed?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would.  I thought showing the OP that throwing in some alert() methods is a quick and easy way to troubleshoot.  But yeah, they can be annoying when they're coming up so often, haha.

Comment: True, if it was once per click I wouldn't mind it, but 3.. I just wanted to punch the computer screen.. lol

Comment: After the loop would have been a better spot probably, haha.