# How do I change a CSS class attribute when another div class has a certain value in another attribute?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm kinda new to this but I'm trying to get this to work.

```
<script>
if $('.twentytwenty-handle').css({ 'left': '400px' })
{
    $('.hero').css({ 'display': 'none' });
}
</script>
```

What I actually want to achieve is when `<div class=twentytwenty-handle style=left: 400px;>` and it is equal or greater than `400px`, for `.hero` to dissapear and let's say give `.hero2` a `display: block;` attribute to make `.hero2` appear.

**EDIT:**

The `.twentytwenty-handle` is not a `div` in my `.html` file, but a `div` in the `jquery.twentytwenty.js` file of the ZURB twentytwenty plug-in [github](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty). What I essentially want is that when the `.twentytwenty-handle` is moved all the way ( or almost all the way if possible ) to the right it makes my `.hero` div change into `.hero2`. And also I want it to change into `.hero3` when moved all the way to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mechanism using javaScript to get see what is happening within and element CSS properties. Based on CSSStyleDeclaration.

```js
function testPosition(){  
  var element = document.querySelector('.twentytwenty-handle');
  var cssProps = getComputedStyle(element);
  // console.log(cssProps);
  var trackItem1  = parseInt(cssProps.left);
  console.log("trackItem1:" + trackItem1);
   if (trackItem1 >= 400) {
      //alert("You went over 400");
      //$(".hero").last().addClass( "hilite" );
      //$(".hero").hide();
      $(".hero").fadeOut(500);
   } else{
    $(".hero").fadeIn(500);
  };
    $("#infoBox").html(
  "CSSStyleDeclaratio: " + '<br>' +   
  cssProps.left + '<br>' +
  cssProps.top + '<br>' +
  cssProps.color + '<br>' +
  cssProps.width + '<br>' +
  cssProps.height
  );

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.twentytwenty-handle {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #333;
  color: yellow;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #333;
  color: yellow;
}
.twentytwenty-handle > p, .hero > p {
    padding: 25px 20px;
}

.hilite {
  font-color: red;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#infoBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="testPosition()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Check CSS properties</button> <span>Change 'left' value for .twentytwenty-handle and then click on button. </span>
<div class="twentytwenty-handle">
  <p>This is twentytwenty-handle</p>
</div>

<div class="hero">
  <p>This is hero</p>
</div>
<div id="infoBox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
if ( $('.twentytwenty-handle').css('left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') >= 400 )
{
    $('.hero').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hero2').show();
}
```

I created [a jsFiddle of working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/jpfxn69y/32/).

Hat tip to [zakovyrya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71743/zakovyrya) for https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100653/1430996

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me still

Comment: I should have clarified that in CSS `.twentytwenty-handle` has a value of `50%`. But if I move the handle in my browser all the way to the right its value is `400px`.