# jquery add width + padding;

Tags: jquery

i am trying to do `var width = ($(this).width() + $(this).css('padding-left') + $(this).css('padding-right'));`

do add the width to the padding, so i should end up with width = `200 + 4 + 4 = 208`
instead i end up with 2004px4px;

how can i force it to add them to get 208?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why dont you use outerWidth property instead. http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

```
var width = $(this).width();
var paddingLeft  = parseInt($(this).css('padding-left' ), 10);
var paddingRight = parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'), 10);

var paddedWidth = width + paddingLeft + paddingRight;
```

Or better use the [jSizes](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) plugin as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery).