# How do i get the css properties by specifying its id

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Padding or margin value in pixels as integer using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery)
after reading the above Answers . One of the user exaplained these

```
 alert($("a").css("margin-top"));
```

Now I wanted to do these

```
 alert($("#cool").css("margin-top")); ' #cool is my table id <table id="cool">
```

but it did not work. How do i get the css properties of a tag by specifying its id ?

Comment: The way you show should work. Maybe there is no `margin-top` on that table?

Comment: Please clarify whether it cause an error (& doesn't alert) or it alerts"undefined" ?

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Have you remembered to reference the jQuery script on the page?

Comment: This fiddle seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/PB9NF/ (note that runs in a `$(document).ready()` block.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you didn't put your code inside a pageLoad event :

```
$(function(){ 
   alert($("#cool").css("margin-top"))
})
```

Or you forgot to integrate jQuery.js into your page.