# css layout: image gallery with left-bar

Tags: css, html, css-float, fluid-layout

I'm trying to implement a design with a shrink-wrapped left bar and a fluid main panel, which will allow as many pictures to be shown as the window width will accommodate, without a horizontal scroll bar.

I'm having massive trouble doing this. When I float:left the control bar, the content of the main panel begins to flow around it. Floating the main panel as well solves this, but causes the content to be shrink-wrapped, meaning that the images tend to be lined up in a single column.

Is there any elegant solution to do this?

I've made a mockup of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/PYKwg/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/CXvRn/10/ It's all in the code:

1. I wrapped #main in #mainWrapper
2. I added padding-left 220px to #mainWrapper.
3. I added float:left to "#top .thing" and "#bottom .thing"

Comment: I didn't cheat or guess at the width.. you should have a set width on your elements that are fixed. unless you are doing completely fluid.. in that case it would be like width 15% for left and width 85% for right. if you are not going to set widths then your only left to use javaScript as your solution.

Comment: My controls won't take 15% of a 3800px width display (dual widescreens are common here). Similarly, on a skinny display 15% won't be enough. I'm quite happy with the shrink-wrap behavior of the float:left'd div there. It's the rest of the design that's problematic.

Comment: I've updated the mockup slightly to show that the content is not fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CXvRn/29/

here is the most basic jquery version:
You have to set some constants such as the total horizontal padding and the horizontal margin for the #main. you could derive those using jQuery but if they are never going to change them you might as well set them your self and save some lines of code.

If you'd like to do it with jquery you can figure that out here: [Padding or margin value in pixels as integer using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I finally figured out a css-only solution, below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is "overflow:auto" on the main-content section. This establishes a new frame of block flow, which content won't flow out of (under/behind the floated control section). Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PYKwg/3/embedded/result/

(Thanks Alex)