# Trying to trim 'px' off a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to wrap up my script placeholderRX. All I need to do is get the 'px' off the end of the string returned from this call.

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
   var $input = $(this)
   var $padding = $input.children('.input').css('padding-left');
});
```

This returns "6px". I want to trim the 6 px off and make sure it's an integer so I can then add 2 pixels to it and feed it to the css rule. I'm new to string manipulations in javascript. Help me out!

Comment: `parseInt('6px') -> 6 // integer;`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery/590618#590618 .

Comment: parseInt('6.5px') -> 6 // a PROBLEM;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a basic javascript replace(), parseInt(), or parseFloat() function to remove "px" from your result. Which method you use, depends on what exactly you need.

The following is a shortened version of your code using parse replace() to remove "px".

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
   var padding = $(this).children('.input').css('padding-left').replace("px", "");
});
```

In the above code, "16px" will return "16". "16.7px" will return "16.7px". "16em" will return "16em".

---

The following is a shortened version of your code using parse parseInt() to remove "px" and more.

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
   var padding = parseInt($(this).children('.input').css('padding-left'));
});
```

In the above code, "16px" will return "16". "16.7px" will return "16". "16em" will return "16". As opposed to the first replace() example, this will remove any text, not just "px".

---

The following is a shortened version of your code using parse parseDouble() to remove "px" and more.

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
   var padding = parseDouble($(this).children('.input').css('padding-left'));
});
```

In the above code, "16px" will return "16". "16.7px" will return "16.7". "16em" will return "16". As opposed to parseInt(), this keeps decimals, if you have them for some reason.

---

Of course, you can keep the code lengthy if there is a reason to see the broken up steps taken for future reference, or if the other variables are used for other reasons. This is the long version using parseInt().

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this)
    var padding = $input.children('.input').css('padding-left');
    var paddingInt = parseInt(padding);
});
```

Also, to explain the change in the variable name from $padding to padding. A $ symbol in front of a javascript variable is common usage to distinguish regular javascript variables from jQuery variables, as they have different properties. There is no reason to use $padding because .css() does not return a jQuery object, but rather just a simple string.

In addition, for more complicated searches, you can research regular expressions.

Comment: This is a good answer given the amount of detail; however, I would suggest moving the concise parseInt version to the top.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your rundown of these functions! Very helpful. Adding $ to my variables is a habit from working in other languages :/ They just look more appropriate to me and I'm able to distinguish them faster, but I'm working on breaking this habit lol.

Comment: And parseInt is definitely what I'm looking for. What the script does is grab properties from a form input field. It then creates a new span element using the grabbed properties to overlay placeholder text over the input element. Theres then a few functions that obviously make this span operate like a normal placeholder, hiding and showing it ect. I programmed it like this because I wanted the user to have as much control over their input stylings as possible and still allow for the script to function easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
function size(value){
    return( parseInt( value.replace('px','') ,10) ); 
}
```

---

Use the function like this:

```
size("32px"); // Returns 32 as an integer
```

Comment: You don't need the `value.replace(...)` section of the code at all - using a simple `parseInt()` call will remove any trailing non-integer tokens.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I just want to be safe

Comment: Unless the string reads something like `3px2`, it won't make a difference - it's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(form).children('.inputSpan').each(function() {
   var $input = $(this)
   var $padding = $input.children('.input').css('padding-left');

   $padding = $padding.substring(0, $padding.Length - 2);
});
```