# jQuery - css() not working properly in firefox

Tags: jquery

I am using `.css()` to get style from a element.
But in firefox `.css()` is not getting value of `margin` and `padding` from element.

Please see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/fMTsW/

**This is my jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        this.value = $('h3').css(this.name);
    });
});
```

**My html code**

```
<h3 style="margin:20px;padding:20px;font-size:30px;font-family:'open sans';">
    I am heading 3
</h3>

<input name="margin" />
<input name="padding" />
<input name="font-size" />
<input name="font-family" />
```

Comment: NO, please check carefully.. wait what browser you are using??

Comment: the latest version of chrome i think.

Comment: I am using latest firefox

Comment: i see. it doesn't works on firefox.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, any solution ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/590618/761793 Things like `margin:` and `padding:` are just shortcuts for `margin-top`, etc. From the doc: http://api.jquery.com/css/ "Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on."

Comment: @HowToPlease. Here's the rescue team. ahehehe. :). now i understand too. thanks much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CSS tag 'margin & padding' is actually a shorthand for the four separate margin/padding values, top/left/bottom/right. Use css('marginTop'), etc. - note they will have 'px' on the end if you have specified them that way.

Use parseInt() around the result to turn it in to the number value.

```
<input name="margin-top" />
<input name="padding-top" />
```

OR

```
<input name="marginTop" />
<input name="paddingTop" />
```

This will give you the value. Using this technique you can get the value of margin and padding.

Comment: It's strange that the shorthands work in jQuery in Chrome, but not jQuery Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because properties like `margin` and `padding` are short hand property and jQuery cannot give you these values you have use independant values such as `margin-top` and `margin-right`.

Moreover, properties with multiple words like `margin-top` should be accessed using `marginTop` i.e **First letter of second word should be capital**.

For a full set of values:

```
<input name="marginTop" />
<input name="marginRight" />
<input name="paddingTop" />
<input name="paddingRight" />
<input name="fontSize" />
<input name="fontFamily" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/fMTsW/) i tried changing the HTML.

From

```
<input name="margin"/>
<input name="padding"/>
```

To

```
<input name="margin-left"/>
<input name="padding-left"/>
```

and the values were set in the inputs value field correctly. This is because the `margin` in css is a keyword which set value of attributes like margin-right, margin-left,margin-top,margin-bottom to a value but it by itself is not a attribute.