# jQuery $(element).css('gap') not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

Why does this work in Chrome but not in Firefox? (im using Firefox v88)
I couldn't find any reliable information about this issue, maybe someone can help me out with this?

Edit: The CSS renders correct, but the js Output is not working

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  alert('Size:' + $('.flex').css('gap'));
});
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
.flex div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div>Box1</div>
  <div>Box2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Relevant: https://caniuse.com/?search=gap  (tl;dr says it should be ok for Firefox v61+)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [jQuery - css() not working properly in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737474/jquery-css-not-working-properly-in-firefox)
gap is only the shorthand for 'column-gap' and 'row-gap'.
Apparently the shorthand spelling is only supported by Chrome.