# How to compare margin-left of an element with a negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

What is the right way to use a jquery if statement where you check if the margin is more negative (less) than an negative value?

```
if(canvas.css('margin-left') <= '-200px') {
       //do something
}
```

Comment: You are using that as a string. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590602/padding-or-margin-value-in-pixels-as-integer-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method will return the *margin-left* value with "px" So you have to use **[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** to get the integer out of it and then compare with any valid value.

Try this

```
var marginLeftValue = parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10);
if (marginLeftValue <= -200) {
       //do something
}
```

PS: If you also want to handle the case of `margin-left: auto` then you should use this as well.

```
marginLeftValue = isNaN(marginLeftValue) ? 0 : marginLeftValue;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that did the trick :) Can accept your awnser yet, i will when i can :)

Comment: Oh wow, parseInt will strip characters from a string like that? Interesting. And pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt()` for converting string to integer, it will only return pixel value and remove the `px` from it.

```
if(parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'),10) <= -200) {
       //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

convert value in  `integer` and than check if it's valid number using [.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```
var marginLeft = parseInt(canvas.css('margin-left'), 10);
if (isNaN(marginLeft)) {
    if (marginLeft <= -200) {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
parseInt(canvas.css("margin-left")<='-200');
```